# Am i allowed to register more than one Backup Agent?

Tags: android, backup

In my android backup, i want to backup the SharedPreferences and some Data stored in a SQL database.

Is it possible to register two backupAgents in the android manifest (one for each) or do i have to implement my own custom manager which stores both?

If its possible

```
<application
    android:backupAgent=".SharedPrefBackupAgentHelper"
    android:backupAgent=".SQLBackupAgent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at this, as I just started using the Data Backup API.
But, I believe if you declare an attribute twice, it will only use one of them.
So in this case, you would have only actually registered `.SQLBackupAgent`

What I'd do is have one BackupAgent class, for example, `.MultiBackupAgent`.
Then that class would initialize and call the methods of your two backup agents.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have more than one designated backup agent class for your application.  You just need to write your agent's onBackup() / onRestore() logic to handle all the various kinds of data that you need to save & restore.  Some people choose to do this by deriving their agent class from BackupAgentHelper and then writing separate BackupHelper subclasses for the different kinds of data that they want to store, for example.  That is not necessary, of course; you can just do it all explicitly in your agent class -- it's basically just a matter of figuring out what will work best for you.